# Adding date to the key expression in s3 sink properties of spring cloud stream

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

We have a spring cloud data flow stream, which processes input files and produces output files in S3 bucket.
We are using following key-expression property to specify the folder for the output file.

app.s3-sink-rabbit.s3.key-expression='XYZ/abc/'+headers.file_name

We are trying to add date in YYYYMMDD as folder for our output files.
i.e. output location should be XYZ/abc/20230110/{filename}

We understood that folder gets created automatically in S3 if it is not found, while generating file.
We could append date in YYYYMMDD and then '/' to the file name through program, but we want to know if it can be done through some expression in property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following may do what you want:

```
app.s3-sink-rabbit.s3.key-expression='XYZ/abc/'+T(java.time.LocalDate).now().format(T(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter).BASIC_ISO_DATE)+'/'+headers.file_name
```

Comment: Hi Corneil, I tried with the expression, but it has not worked as expected. No file generated in the folder as expected.

Comment: I'm fixing the expression.

Comment: Thank you @Corneil, I could do it with following expression
app.s3-source-sink.s3.consumer.key-expression='XYZ/abc/'.concat(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyyMMdd').format(new java.util.Date())).concat('/').concat(headers.file_name) 
I will try with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [key-expression](https://docs.spring.io/stream-applications/docs/current/reference/html/#spring-cloud-stream-modules-s3-sink) property.

From the S3MessageHandler javadocs...

> An S3 Object {@code key} for upload and download can be determined by the provided {@link #keyExpression} or the {@link File#getName()} is used directly. The former has precedence.

Comment: Hi onobc, we are using key-expression property which is also mentioned in my question. What we need is an expression which evaluates to the current date in YYYYMMDD format

Comment: HI @VenuGopal, I missed that detail :)   I believe the answer from pcorneil should work. Also, anywhere you see "expression" props in dataflow/stream app they will support SpEL which is very powerful - see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/reference/html/core.html#expressions-language-ref for more details on literals, vars, etc..

Comment: Hi onobc, thanks for your reply. I tried with coroneil's answer, but it has not worked. I could deploy the stream with that key-expression, but no folder got created and file could not be transferred to the folder as expected.

Comment: Hi @VenuGopal, I verified the suggested SpEL is valid (evaluated eg. "XYZ/abc/20230113/someFile.txt"). Was the original key-expression you posted `'XYZ/abc/'+headers.file_name'` working for you? If so, this one should too. I would try to hardcode it such as `'XYZ/abc/20230113/'+headers.file_name` just to make sure that it will respect the change. Then if that works I would add back in the date SpEL.

Comment: My initial example didn't have T(java class name) around the Java class references.